# Encrypt PHP source code in Yii

Tags: php, yii

Is there any Yii specific ways available to encrypt the source code? I do not want my client to see my source code. I want to encrypt all my PHP files and codes. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/).Best way to encrypt all PHP Source codes.

Other methods are

[Ion Cube](http://www.ioncube.com/php_encoder.php)

[Source Guardian](http://www.sourceguardian.com/text-features-page-160.html)

[phpSHIELD](http://www.phpshield.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Surley there are ways to encode the project like 
[Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/)
 and 
 [IonCube](http://www.ioncube.com/sa_encoder.php) 
but you will have to pay for them and yes while encrypting the code do not forget the [Yii license](http://www.yiiframework.com/license/)