# PHP - BLENC extension - Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii, frameworks, blenc

I am trying to protect some piece of code of my web system application.

For this pourpouse, I am trying to use the BLENC extension for PHP.

**The reason**:

> Because the client demands it, so please dont mix the topic.

**The Problem**:

> It results that the BLENC extension works fine with simple scripts, BUT ... my web app is made using the YII framework, and when I try to access the website it returns the following Error Message ...

Error output in my browser:

```
include(Controller.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory 

/opt/lampp/htdocs/vial/yii/framework/YiiBase.php(427)

                    {
                         include($classFile);
                         if(YII_DEBUG && basename(realpath($classFile))!==$className.'.php')
                             throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','Class name "{class}" does not match class file "{file}".', array(
                                 '{class}'=>$className,
                                 '{file}'=>$classFile,
                             )));
                         break;
                     }
                 }
             }
             else
                 include($className.'.php'); //<-----ERROR POINTING HERE
         }
         else  // class name with namespace in PHP 5.3
         {
             $namespace=str_replace('\\','.',ltrim($className,'\\'));
             if(($path=self::getPathOfAlias($namespace))!==false)
                 include($path.'.php');
             else
                 return false;
         }
         return class_exists($className,false) || interface_exists($className,false);
     }
     return true;
```

**Extra**:

The only thing I did , is to activate the BLENC extension in "php.ini" with the lines:

```
extension=blenc.so
blenc.key_file="/opt/lampp...."
```

I did not encrypth any php file, and I get this error message.

**Extra 2**:

When I deactivate the extension in the "php.ini" my web app runs normally again .... SO....

**The Question**:

Whats going on ?, I added the extension to PHP (that I know it works fine), BUT I dont encrypth any php file, Try to run my web app, and I get errors .... I dont know whats happening.

It doesnt matter if I have or not encrypthed files ... as soon as I activate the extension ... my web app stops working showing me the Yii Framework Error Messages.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Yii autoloading system gets broken.

So maybe autoloader fails because Blenc has its own autoloader that somehow affects Yii's.

Maybe PATH is changed when extension is loaded, even so I'm not sure how Yii uses it.

Also make sure it is not a issue with Yii or the extension but with the naming of the files. Yii won't load a class named "Controller" if the file name is "controller.php" or inside the file the definition of the class has different case, it must match the case. In Windows things might work but in Linux it is always case sensitive.

Links:

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/22756-why-does-autoload-not-work/
[Encrypt PHP source code in Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896647/encrypt-php-source-code-in-yii)

So maybe you can test another tool and see if you get the same error so you then know if it should be Yii or it is because of something inside that extension.

Comment: thanks in advance, I will keep looking and when I have news, I will let you know.